# Javascript, trying to get conversion average

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that is setting conversion rates depending on input boxes (works fine), however I now want to get an average of these rates.

My Code is

```
var avg1 = $('#conversion1').text();
var avg2 = $('#conversion2').text();
var avg3 = $('#conversion3').text();
var avg4 = $('#conversion4').text();
var avg5 = $('#conversion5').text();
var avg6 = $('#conversion6').text();
var sumavg = (avg1 + avg2 + avg3 + avg4 + avg5 + avg6) / 6;
sumavg = Math.round(sumavg*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2);
$('#conversion7').html(sumavg);
```

The id conversion1,2 etc have a number from 0-100 (the conversion rate). However whenever I run this script I get all sorts of crazy numbers for the average (sumavg or id conversion7). I do not know why! I should also note that this bit of code is inside of the function doing the conversion for each day which works fine.

See below for entire snippet:

```
// Conversion Rate

 $.fn.sumConv = function(customers) {
var sum = 0; 
var val = 0
this.each(function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':input') ) {
        val = $(this).val();
    } else {
        val = $(this).text();
    }
    customersval = $(customers).val();
    sum = (customersval/val) * 100;

    //sum += parseFloat( ('0' + val).replace(/[^0-9-\.]/g, ''), 10 );
    sum = Math.round(sum*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2);
    if(sum=="Infinity" || sum=="NaN") sum=0;

});
    // do average
var avg1 = $('#conversion1').text();
var avg2 = $('#conversion2').text();
var avg3 = $('#conversion3').text();
var avg4 = $('#conversion4').text();
var avg5 = $('#conversion5').text();
var avg6 = $('#conversion6').text();
var sumavg = (avg1 + avg2 + avg3 + avg4 + avg5 + avg6) / 6;
sumavg = Math.round(sumavg*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2);
$('#conversion7').html(sumavg);
return sum;
   };

$('input#foot1').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#conversion1').html( $('input#foot1').sumConv('input#customers1') );
});
$('input#customers1').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#conversion1').html( $('input#foot1').sumConv('input#customers1') );
});
$('input#foot2').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#conversion2').html( $('input#foot2').sumConv('input#customers2') );
});
$('input#customers2').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#conversion2').html( $('input#foot2').sumConv('input#customers2') );
});
$('input#foot3').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#conversion3').html( $('input#foot3').sumConv('input#customers3') );
});
$('input#customers3').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#conversion3').html( $('input#foot3').sumConv('input#customers3') );
});
$('input#foot4').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#conversion4').html( $('input#foot4').sumConv('input#customers4') );
});
$('input#customers4').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#conversion4').html( $('input#foot4').sumConv('input#customers4') );
});
$('input#foot5').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#conversion5').html( $('input#foot5').sumConv('input#customers5') );
});
$('input#customers5').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#conversion5').html( $('input#foot5').sumConv('input#customers5') );
});
$('input#foot6').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#conversion6').html( $('input#foot6').sumConv('input#customers6') );
});
$('input#customers6').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#conversion6').html( $('input#foot6').sumConv('input#customers6') );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have to apply `parseFloat` to your data. `text` method returns string, not number. Take a look at the simple example:

```
var avg1 = "1";
var avg2 = "1";
var avg3 = "1";
var avg4 = "1";
var avg5 = "1";
var avg6 = "1";
var sumavg = (avg1 + avg2 + avg3 + avg4 + avg5 + avg6) / 6;
```

`sumavg` will be 18518.5 and not 1.

Wrap all `avg` data with `parseFloat`:

```
var avgN = parseFloat($('#conversionN').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're repeating a lot of code, so I advise employing a DRY technique to minimise that -- e.g. make a `bindKeyUp` function...

Anyway, you need numbers. `.text()` returns strings. E.g. `"99" + "77" === "9977"`. This is where your crazy numbers might be coming from. Try this:

```
var avg1 = ~~$('#conversion1').text();
var avg2 = ~~$('#conversion2').text();
// repeat
```

*`~~` just converts its operand to a number (and floors it towards 0). [More info](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/double-bitwise-not/).*

Or, to make it clearer, use `parseFloat`:

```
var avg1 = parseFloat($('#conversion1').text());
var avg2 = parseFloat($('#conversion2').text());
// repeat
```